# Renaming variable names in R.

Tags: r, warnings, data-cleaning

I want to replace "LF" with "Low Fat" and this is the code i used:

```
train$Item_Fat_Content[train$Item_Fat_Content =="LF"]= "Low FAt"
```

When I  executed the code I got the warning message stating:

```
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, train$Item_Fat_Content == "LF", value = c(3L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert it to `character` class and then do the assignment

```
train$Item_Fat_Content <- as.character( train$Item_Fat_Content)
train$Item_Fat_Content[train$Item_Fat_Content =="LF"]= "Low FAt"
```

---

Or if we want to preserve the `class` as `factor`, before doing the assignment, create a `level` as "Low FAt" and then do the assignment

```
levels(train$Item_Fat_Content) <- c(levels(train$Item_Fat_Content), "Low FAt")
```

NOTE: As @doviod mentioned in the comments, while reading the data with `read.table/read.csv`, use the `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` if we want to have non-numeric columns as `character` class (unless there is a specific reason to have `factor` columns)

Comment: For future reference, you might want to make sure you add `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to your `read.whatever` call.